# Is there any desktop environment that allows to set a different screen scale without changing the screen resolution?

Tags: gnu-screen, cinnamon, display, resolution

I have a 14" Full HD laptop and connect a 23" Full HD monitor to it. Which is approximately 157 PPI and 96 PPI. Changing the screen scale changes the screen resolution, which makes the image and fonts quality much worse. In Win 10, I can change the scale that does not affect the resolution.

My distro: Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon. I was looking for a solution and found none that would not deteriorate the image quality. I find that manually changing the resolution is even better than setting fractional scaling.
[display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVQEY.png)

Is there any desktop environment that does not have such a problem when changing the screen scale?